# Can't figure out why my function is not passing the first number of a file, but passes the last number twice

Tags: c

for some reason I can't figure out why my function is not passing the first number of a data file, but it reads the last number twice. Its obviously something small in the search_mpn_table function, but I just can't put my finger on it because I'm relatively new to coding. Thanks in advance.

```
int search_mpn_table(bacteria_t z[], int size, char combo[])
{
    int i;
    int combocorrect=-1;

    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(z[i].combo,combo)==0)
        {   
            combocorrect=i;
            printf("%s\n", z[i].combo);
        }
    }
    return combocorrect;
}
```

I loaded it into the z array and I printed it correctly in a function that I didn't include here. Here is my call to the function in the main.

```
FILE *outfilep=fopen(foutput,"a");
FILE *inputu=fopen("user_input","r");

status=fscanf(inputu,"%s", combo);
while(status!=EOF)
{
    status=fscanf(inputu,"%s", combo);
    correct=search_mpn_table(z,datasize,combo);
    if(correct==-1)
    {
        fprintf(outfilep,"\nCombination of Positives were not found for %s", combo);
    }

    else
    {
        fprintf(outfilep,"\n%s MPN=%d, 95 pct of examples contain between %d and %d Bacteria per 100mL.", z[correct].combo, z[correct].mpn, z[correct].upper, z[correct].lower);
    }
}
fclose(inputu);
fclose(outfilep);
return 0;
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Please read about [ask] specially the [mcve] part.

Comment: But you can read [ask], I presume?

Comment: Wow! that was coincidence …

Comment: should probably pre increment or change the until to .size-1

Comment: Don't see anything to do with a file in your example.

Comment: This looks ok, the mistake is somewhere else; my guess would be in the place where you fill up your z[] array. The fact that the program is printing the last record twice hints that data is already recorded that way in the array. Try just printing z[] without comparing strings first and see what initial data looks like.

Comment: Figured it was a misused `EOF` problem.

Answer (score 1):

You call fscanf before the loop and then again the first moment inside the loop. So, your program ignores (overwrites) the first line of input.   You also process the last line of input twice because after fscanf (most likely) fails on EOF inside the loop you still process combo, which still contains the last line of input that you've already processed.

Move the fscanfs into the while statement like this:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define STR(x) #x
#define SSTR(x) STR(x)

#define MAX_STR 1024

void process(FILE *out, const char *str)
{
  fprintf(out, "%s\n", str);      
}

int main()
{
  FILE *outfilep = fopen("user_output", "a");
  FILE *inputu   = fopen("user_input",  "r");
  char  combo[MAX_STR + 1];
  int   status;

  if (outfilep == NULL || inputu == NULL)
    abort();

  while ((status = fscanf(inputu, "%" SSTR(MAX_STR) "s", combo)) == 1)
  {
    process(outfilep, combo);

    /* do other stuff */
  }

  fclose(inputu);
  fclose(outfilep);

  return 0;
}
```